# Add yourself to sudoers list

Tags: sudo

I am locked out on ubuntu after a recent update/upgrade.
I have disabled remote root login to my VPS.
I can access my VPS through SSH or via digitial ocean console but I am unable to issue 'sudo' command, on entering my password it says: 
"asad is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported."

Comment: If you can't get into your VPS by ssh with sudo powers you should see if your provider offers VNC or emergency access or similar.  Most do offer something along those lines which helps prevent total lockouts.

Comment: You can't `su` to root once you are logged on?

Comment: @ThomasWard I have ssh access to my VPS but i can't issue sudo commands on my VPS shell. for security reasons, I have disabled remote root acces, I have added my personal machines SSH keys to my remote VPS and its working fine. I have shell access on my VPS

Comment: @user4556274 I can't

Comment: issue resolved. i have rested root password from Digital Ocean Dashboard, got remote root access via root user and added myself to sudoers.

Answer (score 0):

In Digital Ocean, if you have disabled root access via SSH and are locked out of your VPS, you can always access it from browser through "Console access" in control panel.
[image: DO control panel]

You can rest your root password first if you don't remember and then use that to access your droplet.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into your server with your user
2. use `su` command and log in via `root` password.
3. type `usermod -aG sudo asad`

you're done.

Comment: `su` doesn't work according to OP.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, what doesn't work is `sudo`, not `su`

Comment: Read the comments! Someone asks about `su` and OP replies that the root account is disabled.

Comment: @DavidFoerster it says "remote root login", so he can connect to his server with his nirmal user, and type in `su`, that's it.